# skip unwanted entries when running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked a question about this before and then I have been helped wonderfully with the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub box()
 Dim boxVal As String, tbl As ListObject, shBox As Worksheet, rngRef As Range, x As Long
 Dim shelvNo As Long, rackNo As Long
 Dim iRow As Long:   iRow = 1  ' row where "rack" exist
 Dim iCol As Long:    iCol = 1 'column letter where "rack" exists (C:C)

 Set tbl = Sheets("Register").ListObjects("Table1")
 For x = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count  'on the frist row there are ABC, ABC etc.
    If tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 1) = "" Then Exit For
    boxVal = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 6).Value
    On Error Resume Next
     Set shBox = Sheets("Box " & boxVal) 'set the sheet of the appropriate box  'set the sheet of the appropriate box
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No sheet named """ & "box " & tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 6).Value & """ exists" & vbCrLf & _
                "Please, create it and run the code again!": Exit Sub

     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rngRef = shBox.Cells(iRow, iCol)
     shelvNo = iRow + 1 + tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 7).Value
     rackNo = iCol + tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 8).Value - 1
     rngRef.Offset(shelvNo, rackNo).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 2).Value & " " & tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 3).Value
 Next x
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I now have to use it on a different dataset that does contain values in the **Box** column (Column F) that do not have a separate excel sheet and therefore would generate an error because there is no separate sheet. I do not need sheets to be creates for those entries, they simply have to be ignored when filling the other sheets. (See Picture for how it should be. The blue arrow is how the information should be filled in on the sheet indicated with the orange arrow)

[image]

So now I am trying to skip/ignore the entries that generate errors completely but so far I haven't been able to. If I just say : `on error resume next` , I end up with data being filled in the excel sheets **box 10/ box 20/..**  that should not be filled in (It does work wonderfully if my dataset does not contain any entries that would cause an error, e.g. if my data set only contains values for box 10,20,30 and 40. (See picture 2 for how it is now, the actual locations of information filled in is random in this example).

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function maybe like this to determine if each sheet exists, as a boolean value?:

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional Workbook As Workbook) As Boolean
If Workbook Is Nothing Then Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim sht As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = Workbook.Sheets(SheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

In your main sub you can then skip the `On Error` bit and write:

```
If SheetExists("Box " & boxVal) Then
...
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me;) 
I understand what it should do..
But I am not yet able to get it to work for me.

I have asked a colleague if she could figure it out but no luck so far.
Now it seems to skip everything